# Jboss Rules (Drools) name origination

Tags: drools

What is the origin of the word 'drools'?
I didn't found any such information around.
Is it an abbreviation, if so what does it stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a play on the word "rules" nothing more, just a bit of fun. I wouldn't read too much into it, there was no obvious or real intention from it.